# Styles css file isnt applied to my site because of the new windows update i guess

Tags: css, node.js

I am doing an online course and we created a site Blog App and a few days ago it worked perfectly. Today when i wanted to see it i saw that the styles are no more applying(app.css)

I have all the paths and names and code exactly like the teachers. I searched for like 3 hours to solve it but nothing solved it.

I also talked to a student from this course and the site is working perfectly for him, but he has mac.

I think the problem is from the new windows update.. but idk how to solve it. If anyone knows about this please help

Comment: Hi Bianca: This site won't be able to help you based on the information you provided.  If you post code snippets, we can review them and try to see where the error is.  I can tell you that it's very unlikely that a windows update caused your CSS to stop working. It sounds like there is likely a typo somewhere.

Comment: My guess (since you didn't provide enough information) is that you were using a cached css file and changed the name or location along the way. When the cache was cleared file is no longer found. Check the link path and verify the file still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by changing the directory name.. with the name "stylesheets" it does not work. It was no typo or wrong paths.